# How to substitute an array in a given expression in Maple?

Tags: maple

Given e.g.

```
  f := a[1]*a[2]+a[1]*a[3]+a[2]*a[3]
```

Now we want to substitute a[i]->i, I tried

```
   applyrule(a[i] = i, f)
   applyrule(a =[seq(i, i = 1 .. nops(a))], f)
```

and replace "applyrule" above with "subs" and "algsubs" commands. But none works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

> eval(f, a=[$1..3]);